# Очень много Warning'ов

Tags: php

Еще раз всем привет. Я решил одну ошибку PHP, теперь файл : [login.php](http://http//travianx5.ru/login.php) и файл регистрации загружаются, но выдают целый рой Warning'ов. И мне так кажется, что большинство из них связанны с выставлением нужных прав на папки и файлы. Но также есть куча других ошибок. Хотя до этого запускал на локалхосте и все было ОК. Почему так происходит?

```
function countUser() {
        $q = "SELECT count(id) FROM " . TB_PREFIX . "users WHERE id > 5";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $q);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        return $row[0];
    }
```

Вот код в котором происходит первая ошибка в обеих файлах. Однако сейчас БД еще пустая и пользователя с id > 5 просто не существует, может из-за этого возникает ошибка?

На главной странице тоже есть три warning'a, такого типа:

**Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /var/www/index.php on line 129**

Однако если зайти на скрипт [testmysql.php](http://travianx5.ru/testmysql.php), то пишет "Connection OK".

Помогите разобраться. Буду благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: какие waringи ?

Comment: Вы увидите, если перейдете по ссылкам в вопросе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не может быть, а точно ошибка возникает потому, что у вас бд пустая.
**mysqli_fetch_row** ожидает, что вы передадите ему ресурс. А вы передаете ему булево значение (в переменной **$q** у вас значение false, потому что выборка пустая).

Добавьте проверки на то, что у вас пришло в результате запроса. Если запрос вернул пустой результат - один шаблон действий. Если запрос вернул какой-то результат - другой.

Comment: вот это телепатия...

Comment: @eicto, не, я просто по ссылкам перешел, которые в вопросе указаны. :)

Comment: Небольшая поправка mysqli_fetch_assoc() возвращает объект, а не ресурс.

Comment: @eprivalov1 , @VenZell сказал что `mysqli_fetch_assoc() `  не возвращает а получает, аргументом false,

Comment: Спс, уже разбираюсь, что не так.